# Проблема отображения шрифта при обращении к $_SESSION

Tags: php, html, css

Не отображаются некоторые буквы в шрифте где идет обращение через суперглобальную переменную `$_SESSION`. Например здесь:

```
<?php echo 'E-mail: '.$_SESSION['USER_EMAIL'].'';?>
```

В остальных случаях шрифт работает нормально. Подскажите, пожалуйста, где ошибка.

Стили подключаются через php функцию `Head`:

```
<?php 
        function Head($p1, $p2, $p3) {
        echo '<!DOCTYPE html>
        <html lang="ru">
          <head>
            <meta http-equiv="Content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
            <meta name="keywords" content= "'.$p2.'">
            <meta name="description" content= "'.$p3.'">
            <link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="/resourse/CSS/images/ICO.png">
            <title>'.$p1.'</title>
            <link rel="stylesheet"  href="/resourse/css/fonts.css">
            <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/resourse/css/style.css">
            <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.1/jquery.min.js" type="text/javascript" ></script>
            <script src="script.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
              </head>';
        }
        ?>
```

fonts.css выглядит так:

```
 @font-face {
        font-family: 'ALS_Meringue';
        src: url('fonts/meringue_typeface_regular.eot');
        src: url('fonts/meringue_typeface_regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'),
        url('fonts/meringue_typeface_regular.ttf') format('truetype'),
        url('fonts/meringue_typeface_regular.woff') format('woff'),
        url('font/meringue_typeface_regular.svg') format('svg');
        font-weight: normal;
        font-style: normal; 

    }
```

Comment: смотрите html-код страницы, если там все на месте, то проблема в самом шрифте

Comment: Да, видимо проблема с самим шрифтом, при замене на Arial все отлично работает. Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Все работает, решено заменой шрифта.